# Как происходит обращение к методу через переменную?

Tags: java, android, методы, ссылки, класс

Есть строки:

```
CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(this);
mCrimes = crimeLab.getCrimes();
```

Есть класс:

```
public class CrimeLab {
    private static CrimeLab sCrimeLab;

    private List<Crime> mCrimes;

    public static CrimeLab get(Context context) {
        if (sCrimeLab == null) {
            sCrimeLab = new CrimeLab(context);
        }
        return sCrimeLab;
    }

    private CrimeLab(Context context) {
        mCrimes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Crime crime = new Crime();
            crime.setTitle("Crime #" + i);
            crime.setSolved(i % 2 == 0);
            mCrimes.add(crime);
        }
    }

    public List<Crime> getCrimes() {
        return mCrimes;
    }

    public Crime getCrime(UUID id) {
        for (Crime crime : mCrimes) {
            if (crime.getId().equals(id)) {
                return crime;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

В данном случае я не очень понимаю принцип вызова метода getCrimes(), так как вызвать его с помощью класса `CrimeLab.getCrime()` нельзя, ибо метод не статический, вызвать с помощью ссылки `new CrimeLab.getCrime()` тоже нельзя, так как класс CrimeLab имеет только приватный конструктор. 
Почему тогда этот метод можно вызвать с помощью переменной crimeLab?

Comment: Объект класса создаётся (если не был ранее создан) и возвращается в методе `get`, который и вызывается в самой первой строке `CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(this);`. Далее у этого объекта вызывается публичный метод `getCrimes`. Тут представлен паттерн [singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод нельзя вызвать с помощью `new CrimeLab.getCrime()` не из-за каких-то ограничений метода, а потому, что нельзя вызвать саму строку `new CrimeLab.getCrime()`.

*Зачем так делать?*

1. Почему приватный конструктор:

   Это учебный пример, в реальности Вы не будете генерировать данные при создании `CrimeLab`, Вы будете читать их из файла/БД/сети/ввода пользователя с другого экрана.

   Вам будет необходимо гарантировать, что данные **одинаковы для всех экранов**. //*причина, по которой конструктор сделан приватным*

   Итак, мы имеем класс, у которого приватный конструктор, поэтому `new CrimeLab.getCrime()` уже не работает.
2. Почему не статический метод?

   Вам нужно минимизировать число долгих операций (получаете данные в конструкторе и больше никогда, конструктор вызывается **один** раз).

   То есть, если Вы сделаете просто статический метод, то **каждый** раз будете обращаться, например, в сеть, что может занимать **секунды** времени. Пользователи не любят, когда все работает так медленно.

   Итак, мы приходим к выводу, что статический метод не подходит. (потому он и не сделан в книге статическим)

Остается только тот вариант, который у Вас в вопросе. Всё в целом это называется паттерн `Singleton`.

Если что-то осталось непонятно после моего объяснения - поищите в интернете, паттерн очень старый, про него много всего есть в книгах/статьях.